# How to join twice a single table in sequelize using following and followers example

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This code is running perfectly. i can get following and followers now i need to see that followers that i am getting is i am also following them ?

This is the question that how can i make another query/subQuery to Followers table and see that i am also following to my followers.

Follower Table

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Follower', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    followingId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
}
```

Association

```
db.Follower.belongsTo(db.User, {as:'following', foreignKey: 'followingId'});
db.Follower.belongsTo(db.User, {as:'follower', foreignKey: 'userId'});
```

Query

```
Follower.findAll({
        where: {
            followingId: userId
        },
        attributes: ['_id'],
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: ['fullName', 'username', '_id', 'picture'],
            as: 'follower'
          }
        ]
    })
```

**UPDATE**

I have achieve desired result form row query :

```
SELECT  F.userId, F.`followingId` , F1.`followingId` as IsFollowing , U.`fullName` FROM Followers as F

INNER JOIN Users as U ON userId = U._id

LEFT JOIN Followers as F1 On F.userId = F1.followingId

WHERE F.followingId = 142
```

Still struggling in sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

to transform your row query into sequlize request try this:

Association

```
db.Follower.belongsTo(db.User, {as: 'following', foreignKey: 'followingId', sourceKey: 'userId'});
db.Follower.hasOne(db.User, {as: 'follower', foreignKey: 'userId'});
```

Query

```
Follower.findAll({
  where: {
    followingId: userId
  },
  attributes: ['userId', 'followingId'],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: ['fullName'],
      as: 'follower',
      required: true // to get inner join
    },
    {
      model: Follower,
      attributes: [['followingId', 'IsFollowing']],
      as: 'following',
      required: false // to get left join
    }
  ]
});
```